# Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve a large set of non-linear equation using fsolve in MATLAB 2013. When I run this code:

```
Unkn0=zeros(3249,1); % Guess
[Unkn,feval,exitflag,output]=fsolve(Eqnh,Unkn0);
```

Here Eqnh is a function handle for 3249 variables and 3249 equations.
I get the following error:

```
Error using
Not enough input arguments.
Error in fsolve (line 218)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

I can provide Eqnh written in a text file if there is any need of it.

Comment: Can you provide a mock `Eqnh` that is musch smaller, maybe 3 Variables and 3 Equations?

Comment: @Dan I substituted my initial guess into the function and it even evaluated it. But some of the equations became `Nan`, so I think the problem is with my initial guess. Still you can have a look at `Eqnh` if there could be some other problem with it. If you are using gmail then go through this link [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9WkEDuqKNpienl2WkxCaEE1d0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Or 'Eqnh' can also be seen through this dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq8djp4ch7oqgn6/dump.txt)